# Cartopy coastlines not showing

Tags: python, cartopy

I just installed Cartopy and is trying their basic example. The code I'm using is

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_global()
ax.coastlines()
plt.show()
```

What happens is that no coastlines are drawn, what I get is only a white plot.

I have tested drawing some data from a NETCDF file I've gotten, and that seems to work fine so the error seems to be in the coastline drawing.

The coastline files were downloaded to ~/.local/share/cartopy/shapefiles/natural_earth/physical
the first time I ran the example.

Anyone got and idea about what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you modified any of the matplotlib [rc settings](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html)? For instance, having `'patch.linewidth'` set to zero will prevent coastlines from appearing.